# Can't Break the while read loop even if condition is met

Tags: bash, shell

This should be simple but I am missing something, need some help.
My requirement is to read the log file via tail to get latest logs, grep Download Config & Copying all files of and write it in MyOwnLogFile.log but I want this to stop as soon as .myworkisdone file appears in /usr/local/FOLDER/
One thing is sure that .myworkisdone will be generated at the last when all logs are done… but the script just continues to read the log file and never comes out of it, even if the file is created.

```
while [[ ! -e /usr/local/FOLDER/.myworkisdone ]];
do
    sudo tail -f -n0  /var/log/server22.log | while read line; do echo "$line" | grep -e 'Downloading Config’ -e ‘Copying all files of' ; done  >> /var/tmp/MyOwnLogFile.log
done
```

I also tried `until` instead of while to check the file but still the script cant break the spell of reading the log file.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `tail -f` will follow the file indefinitely, the condition in the outer `while` is pretty much checked only once. If you want to terminate the `tail` when the `.myworkisdone` file appears, you'll have to arrange for it to be killed explicitly. But that sounds a bit awkward. Would it be possible to to first wait for the file to appear, and _then_ grep through the complete log file, without `tail -f`?

Comment: Thanks, the purpose is to show log to the support team members so showing logs live is important. :)

Comment: shell is, as usual, exactly the wrong tool for this job.  Use perl's [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Tail) module - it's made for exactly this (monitoring a log file and performing actions when patterns are matched).   BTW, if you're using a while/read loop in some variant of sh, you're almost certainly doing it wrong.  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/7696)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @ikkachu, `tail -f` is an infinite process. However you may use the inner loop to initiate the breaking:

```
while :
do
    tail -f server.log | while IFS= read -r line
    do
        printf '%s\n' "$line" | grep 'word' >> ownlog.log
        if [ -e killer.file ] ; then break ; fi
    done
    break 
done
```

- Why does `break 2` in the if-loop not work?

The pipe initiates a subshell, the `break` command cannot exit this subshell. Hence another `break` in the outer loop.

- When does the script stop?

Once the `killer.file` is existing, the pending `| while read ...` still awaits another entry and holds open the whole thing. I.e. you need the next line, i.e. (with dummy files):

```
 echo test >> server.log
 #"normal" output - nothing happens

 echo word >> server.log
 #matching output - logged to ownlog.log
 
 touch killer.file
 #killer file appears - breaks cannot take effect
 #as "read" still awaits signal.

 echo test2 >> server.log
 #break takes effect
```

This is especially important if the `killer.file` would also indicate that there are no more logs written to `server.log`, so the process remains constantly open.

Comment: For `bash` you could use `read` with a timeout

Comment: hi there, this solution made much sense to me so I tried this first. Works as expected. Thanks a lot. 
This doesnt mean other solutions don't work. I just didnt try those. Please try and see what suits you best. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the checking for the "stop file" from the reading of the log file, because `tail -f` will not exit.  The following shell script does that by having a background task check for the existence of the "stop file" once a second.  Whenever the file appears, it kills the `tail -f` process with a `PIPE` signal (the same signal it would have received if `grep` had stopped reading).  When `tail -f` terminates due to the `PIPE` signal, the `grep` process terminates too since its input  stream closes.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

stopfile=/usr/local/FOLDER/.myworkisdone

set -- tail -f /var/log/server22.log 

"$@" | {
        while true; do
                if [ -e "$stopfile" ]; then
                        pkill -PIPE -fx "$*"
                        break
                fi
                sleep 1
        done &

        grep -e 'Downloading Config' \
             -e 'Copying all files of'
} >/var/tmp/MyOwnLogFile.log
```

This sets the positional parameters to the `tail -f` command. This makes it a bit easier to refer to it with `pkill` later.  The `pkill` utility is called with both `-f` and `-x` to be able to kill exactly the command that we started earlier.

The value `"$*"` is a single string consisting of all positional parameters (the `tail -f` command) with a space in-between them (by default).

Using `bash` and a named array for the `tail -f` command:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

stopfile=/usr/local/FOLDER/.myworkisdone

talicmd=( tail -f /var/log/server22.log )

"${tailcmd[@]}" | {
        while true; do
                if [ -e "$stopfile" ]; then
                        pkill -PIPE -fx "${tailcmd[*]}"
                        break
                fi
                sleep 1
        done &

        grep -e 'Downloading Config' \
             -e 'Copying all files of'
} >/var/tmp/MyOwnLogFile.log
```

(I'm also noticing that a couple of the single quotes around your regular expressions used with `grep` in the question are not ordinary single quotes but "fancy quotes".)

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. This sounds promising but I couldnt try, I think in future releases, I'd have time to test and try this. Thanks for help, again!

Answer (score 0):

perl has a module called [File::Tail](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Tail) designed to monitor log file(s), so your program can take actions if conditions are met (e.g. printing the line if it matches a pattern).

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl

     use File::Tail;
     tie *FH,"File::Tail",(name=>shift,nowait=>1);

     while (<FH>) {
         print if (m/Downloading Config|Copying all files of/);
         exit if ( -e '/usr/local/FOLDER/.myworkisdone')
     }
```

save as, e.g., `watch.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x watch.pl` and run it as:

```
$ ./watch.pl /var/log/server22.log
```

or just embed it as a one-liner in a shell script, same as you would for an awk or sed script:

```
perl -MFile::Tail -e 'tie *FH,"File::Tail",(name=>shift,nowait=>1);
      while (<FH>) {
        print if (m/Downloading Config|Copying all files of/);
        exit if ( -e '/usr/local/FOLDER/.myworkisdone')
      }' /var/log/server22.log
```

This monitors the log file named as the first arg to the script (`name=>shift`).  It prints any logfile lines that match the pattern, and exits if the .myworkisdone file exists.

`nowait=>1` prevents the script from blocking while reading the input file.  It's less than ideal, but OK for a quick-and-dirty script.  A better solution would be to use the File::Tail's `select()` method. See `man File::Tail`.

BTW, the `select()` method also makes it easy to monitor multiple log files at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. The 2nd solution worked at the moment so I'd go ahead with that but in my nxt release for script I'll try what you've suggested. Thanks again. :)